# mysql, space equals empty string

Tags: mysql-5.7

Just took me 2 hours to troubleshoot an issue on my backend.

Cause was that of empty string being equal to space:

```
SELECT ' ' = '';
-> 1

SELECT STRCMP(' ', '');
-> 0 /* means equal */
```

Interestingly enough,

```
SELECT '' REGEXP '[ ]';
-> 0
SELECT '' REGEXP ' ';
-> 0
SELECT ' ' REGEXP ' ';
-> 1
```

Can I prevent this? Is it a setting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason this fails is explained in the docs here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html:

> Values in CHAR and VARCHAR columns are sorted and compared according
>   to the character set collation assigned to the column.
>
> All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR,
>   VARCHAR, and TEXT values in MySQL are compared without regard to any
>   trailing spaces. “Comparison” in this context does not include the
>   LIKE pattern-matching operator, for which trailing spaces are
>   significant.

One way to work around this would be to cast as `BINARY`

```
SELECT BINARY '' = ' ';
0
```

You can also use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT '' LIKE ' ';
0
```

Comment: interesting. But normally `''` and `' '` are placeholders, I don't really want to use LIKE instead of = in all my queries...

Comment: Bu why it is happening? Why '' and ' ' is not false. I have tried this PostgreSQL and it is showing correct output  `False`  but not MySQL

Comment: @Code-Monk - I added an explanation in answer.

Comment: For some reason LIKE does not break my indexes. I think I'll use it as a temporary solution in a few specific queries...

Comment: Sorry for accepting this answer that late, I don't know why I didn't do it before

Answer (score 3):

Not a vanilla MySQL user, but I was having this problem with MariaDB 10.2.9 as well. I solved it by changing my `VARCHAR` column collation from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8mb4_unicode_nopad_ci`.

`SELECT '' = ' ' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
Result: `1`

`SELECT '' = ' ' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_nopad_ci;`
Result: `0`