# MySQL returns incorrect UTF8 extended characters in some cases only

Tags: mysql, unicode, sql-like, cjk, utf8mb4

*Note: In the following question you may see ? or blocks instead of characters, this is because you don't have the appropriate font. Please ignore this.*

## Background

I have a table with data structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `decomposition_dup` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `structure` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `child` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `parent` (`parent`),
 KEY `child` (`child`),
 KEY `parent_2` (`parent`,`child`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=211929 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And some example data:

```
INSERT INTO `decomposition_dup` (`id`, `parent`, `structure`, `child`) VALUES
(154647, '锦', 'a', '钅'),
(154648, '锦', 'a', '帛'),
(185775, '钅', 'd', '二'),
(185774, '钅', 'd', '㇟'),
(21195, '钅', 'd', ''),
(21178, '⻐', 'd', '乇'),
(21177, '⻐', 'd', '');
```

And the charsets are all set correctly:

[image]

## Problem

It is **very important to note** that:

- 154647, 185775, 185774 & 21195 refer to this character: http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E9%92%85
- 21178 and 21177 refer to this character: http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E2%BB%90

As you can see, they are different characters. However, in some cases they are treated as **the same character**.

## Case 1

When I run the following query, it only returns the correct child (i.e. doesn't return the similar-looking but different character child):

```
SELECT *
FROM decomposition_dup
WHERE parent = '锦'
```

[image]

This is correct behaviour.

## Case 2

However, when I run the following query using 钅 (http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E9%92%85) it returns both the similar characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM decomposition_dup
WHERE parent = '钅'
```

[image]

This should only return 185775, 185774 & 21195.

## Case 3

And when I run the following query using ⻐ (http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E2%BB%90) it also returns both the similar characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM decomposition_dup
WHERE parent = '⻐'
```

[image]

This should only return 21178 and 21177.

## Case 4

If I replace `=` with `LIKE` for the broken queries (i.e. Case 2 and Case 3), they return correctly.

For example, the following query is the same as Case 3 but using`LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM decomposition_dup
WHERE parent LIKE '⻐'
```

[image]

This returns the correct characters but slows down the query.

## Question

Is this a bug in MySQL or is there something that I am overlooking when querying for UTF8 extended characters?

Comment: What version of mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be the same, set the `COLLATION` of the columns to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.
If you want them to be different, use `utf8mb4_general_ci`, instead:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX('e99285') USING utf8mb4) =
    ->        CONVERT(UNHEX('e2bb90') USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci AS general;
+---------+
| general |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX('e99285') USING utf8mb4) =
    ->        CONVERT(UNHEX('e2bb90') USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci AS unicode;
+---------+
| unicode |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX('e99285') USING utf8mb4) =
    ->        CONVERT(UNHEX('e2bb90') USING utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci AS unicode_520;
+-------------+
| unicode_520 |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: I will try this when I get home from work, but from what I have read utf8mb4_unicode_ci most accurately differentiates between characters - very strange!  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: Oh but in this case 'utfmb4_general_ci' solves the problem of correctly differentiating between characters e99285 and e2bb90, right?

Comment: Thank you, case closed! It was an encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, general says they are different; unicode[520] say they are the same.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can make out the problem lies within the SQL side of things upon research you'll see that this error code means that

> MySQL's utf8 permits only the Unicode characters that can be
>   represented with 3 bytes in UTF-8.

so It might be the characters you are using within the cases of SQL

Comment: To what error code are you referring? And as of MySQL 5.5.3, the utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character and supports supplemental characters

Comment: The specifics in this thread work the same in utf8 and utf8mb4.  utf8mb4 is a better choice for Chinese, Emoji, and some less common applications/languages.